# Flask session variables not persisting when using fetch

Tags: session, flask, fetch

I have two flask routes setup (defined using Flask Rest-X), as follows.

```
class Send(Resource):

    def get(self: Any) -> Any:
        session['foo'] = 'bar'
        return {'message': session['foo']}


class Receive(Resource):

    def get(self: Any) -> Any:
        return {'message': session.get('foo', 'empty')}
```

Both are registered as endpoints at /send and /receive respectively. There's nothing clever going on here, just two flask endpoints that support GET requests.

When I go to the browser and go to localhost:5000/send.
I get back {'message': 'bar'} as I should. When I then go to localhost:5000/receive, I get back the same. This means that the session is working as it should.

Now I have the following piece of javascript that tries to do exactly the same thing using fetch.

```
fetch(`http://localhost:5000/send`, {
          method: 'GET',
          mode: 'cors',
          credentials: 'same-origin'
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            fetch(`http://localhost:5000/receive`, {
              method: 'GET',
              mode: 'cors',
              credentials: 'same-origin'
            })
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(data => {setResponse(data)})
          })
```

The setResponse(data) line is similar to printing to console, it just writes the output to the screen, eitherway I get back {'message': 'empty'} so using fetch is not setting the session variables properly.

It feels to me like a combination of credentials, and CORS, but I can't seem to get the combination right.

I've tried:

credential: include -> Results in CORS error.

credential: same-origin -> Empty

credential: same-origin and mode: cors -> Empty

Then I tried something new. I added a header to the /receive route like this.

```
class Receive(Resource):

    def get(self: Any) -> Any:
        response = make_response({'message': session.get('me', 'empty')})
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
        return response
```

I then tried credential: include again.. and success!! I got {'message': 'bar'}. So it clearly worked.. but then here's the mysterious part. I changed 'foo' and 'bar' to 'one' and 'two' respectively, and tried again, and now I'm back to {'message': 'empty'}. So why did it suddenly work for foo/bar when I added the response header, and why is that response header not working any more? Is it a caching issue? The combinatorics of this problem is driving me slightly insane.

Anyone got any advice on how to get fetch to work with Flask sessions?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, I think. But I don't know why, so I'd still appreciate it if someone can fill me in, I hate solutions that "just work".

I changed the back end code to the following (added the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header to both send and receive.

```
class Send(Resource):

    def get(self: Any) -> Any:
        session['success'] = 'yes'
        response = make_response({'message': session.get('success', 'empty')})
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
        return response


class Receive(Resource):

    def get(self: Any) -> Any:
        response = make_response({'message': session.get('success', 'empty')})
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
        return response
```

Now it works consistently, I can change the session variable to whatever I want and it always uses the updated value.

Can anyone explain what happened here?